# JqueryUI Autocomplete callback function using val( ) not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jqueryui autocomplete and have set up a search of an image gallery using [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) that when the image is found, a small icon is shown and the user can open the image with a lightbox (prettyphoto )

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    var projects = [
        {
            value: "Alcatraz",
            label: "Alcatraz",          
            icon: "Alcatraz.jpg",
            url: "slides/Alcatraz.jpg",
            desc: "",
            imgN: "1"
        },
        {
            value: "Amber Light",
            label: "Amber Light",           
            icon: "Amber Light.jpg",
            url: "slides/Amber%20Light.jpg",
            desc: "",
            imgN: "2"
        },
        {
            value: "Blue Boat",
            label: "Blue Boat",         
            icon: "Blue Boat.jpg",
            url: "slides/Blue%20Boat.jpg",
            desc: "",
            imgN: "3"
        }
    ];

    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );                
            $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "thumbs/" + ui.item.icon );
            $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
            $( "#project-label" ).html( ui.item.label );
            $( "#project-link" ).attr("href", ui.item.url );
            $( "#project-link" ).attr("title", ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },

        close: function() {
            var value = $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.imgN );
            cf.moveTo(value);
        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + " - " + item.desc + "</a>" )

            .appendTo( ul );
    };

});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="project-label">Search</div>
<a href="#" rel="prettyPhoto" class="" id="project-link"><img id="project-icon" src="res/transparent_1x1.png"/></a>
<input id="project"/>
<input type="hidden" id="project-id"/>
<p id="project-label"></p>
<p id="project-description"></p>
```

The problem I am having is with the following function:

```
close: function() {
            var value = $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.imgN );
            cf.moveTo(value);
        }
```

I need the image gallery to scroll to the specific image in the contentflow using

```
 cf.moveTo();
```

I am not getting my code to return this value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$( "#project" ).val( ui.item.imgN );`: you are assigning the value instead of getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trials and tribulations, I found a way to get this to work with this additional modified code:

```
        select: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#project-imgN" ).val( ui.item.imgN );


            return false;
        },

        close: function(event, ui ) {
        function runEffect() {
        // get effect type from 
        var move = $( "#project-imgN" ).val();

        // run the effect
        cf.moveTo(move);
    };

     runEffect(); 
        }
    })
```

Comment: Would be better to post only the modified code with a bit of explanation so it can help others more easily.

Answer (score 1):

When you use val() you should not enter an argument, thats used to set the value, you just need to call val() on the element you want the value of.

Try:

```
  var value = $( "#project "+ui+"."+item+"."+imgN).val();
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I get the following firebug error: 
ui is not defined
[Break On This Error] var value = $( "#project "+ui+"."+item+"."+imgN).val();

Comment: Sorry I didnt test this, I just wanted to point you in the right direction. If you want to get the value of an element you should use the $("you selector here").val(); syntax. No you should just figure out how to identify your element. Ui is undefined because its not being passed as an argument for the close function. So if you need it, just make it global.